# Deltaspike + Quartz + CronExpressions from custom property file

Tags: java, properties, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression, deltaspike

I've achieved configuring CronExpression from a propery file, but this property file is apache-deltaspike.properties, which is inside the .jar file. I need to take the cron expression from my custom config file:

```
import org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.PropertyFileConfig;

public class myOwnPropertyFileConfig  implements PropertyFileConfig  {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public String getPropertyFileName() {
    return "cfg/myOwnPropFile.properties";
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isOptional() {
    return false;
  }

}
```

myOwnPropFile.properties

```
deltaspike_ordinal=500
property1=value1
property2=value2
QuartzJob=0 25 17 * * ?
```

the job:

```
@Scheduled(cronExpression = "{QuartzJob}")
public class MyQuartzJob implements Job {
  //job code
}
```

Everything goes good when I set this property: QuartzJob=0 25 17 * * ?
inside apache-deltaspike.properties, but when I set it in my own property file, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No config-value found for config-key: QuartzJob
```

Researching, I found that my property file is loaded right after Quartz initialization, and that explains the why. Now, I read in Deltaspike doc that it's possible to get my property file loaded whenever I want, using deltaspike_ordinal inside my property file. So I tried, but it seems to ignore the deltaspike_ordinal=500, and error keeps arising.

So, does someone know how to sort this out? Deltaspike doc also talks about a ConfigSource and so, but it's not so clear and there are no examples.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
The key was to look into the javadoc of PropertyFileConfig:

> 2. Automatic pickup via java.util.ServiceLoader mechanism In case you have an EAR or **you need the configured values already during the CDI
>      container start** then you can also register the PropertyFileConfig via
>      the java.util.ServiceLoader mechanism. To not have this configuration
>      picked up twice it is required to annotate your own PropertyFileConfig
>      implementation with org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.exclude.Exclude.
>
> The ServiceLoader mechanism requires to have a file 
>        META-INF/services/org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.config.PropertyFileConfig   containing the fully qualified Class name of your own
>   PropertyFileConfig implementation class.
>   com.acme.my.own.SomeSpecialPropertyFileConfig   The implementation
>   will look like the following:
>
> ```
> @Exclude
>   public class SomeSpecialPropertyFileConfig implements PropertyFileConfig      {
>       public String getPropertyFileName() {
>           return "myconfig/specialconfig.properties"
>       }
>       public boolean isOptional() {
>           return false;
>       }
>   }
> ```

Worked like a charm